# Cookies Django Project

Tags: javascript, html, django, cookies

I'm writing a django program that interfaces with a page("like a javaapplet" but not) embedded on some other site.

The idea is that I want people to play a puzzle game. But they only get the piece if they answer the question right.

I don't want them to login, I want to give them a cookie instead. But I need to track and make sure the player is who they are so that they can't gain access to the entire puzzle.

I also want to associate that player with the progress they made, and keep track of that progress on my server

Sorry if this is hard to follow.

How do I do this? Is it possible?

I have this code, but need some pointers:

```
def cookietest(request):
    cookie = request.get_signed_cookie('puzzle')
    response = HttpResponse()
    response = render(request, 'cookie.html',{'cookie':cookie})
    response.set_signed_cookie(name='puzzle', value=1, max_age=None)
    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should use [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/), and store the user's progress in the session data. The django session mechanism will take care of the cookie for your.